# is there any statement to turn row value into same row but different column in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, pivot

I hope someone could give me an answer to my problem.

I got a table(namely `table1`) that looks like this and I want it to be something like I show in picture:

[image: My table]

**table1**

```
"number"  "date"        time
 -------  ----------    -----
 001      19.09.2020    12:30
 001      19.09.2020    14:31
 002      19.09.2020    11:20
 001      19.09.2020    17:20
 002      19.09.2020    14:00
 001      19.09.2020    19:01
```

***expected result***(*for **"number"='001'***):

```
"date"      time1  time2  time3  time4
----------  -----  -----  -----  -----
19.09.2020  12:30  14:31  17:20  19:01
```

Comment: Do you want it as columns or a comma separated value for all time column is also suits to your requirement ? If we use `pivot` , are you fine with hard coded values for each number ? Are the rows for each number `001`  unknown ?

Answer (score 1):

There are some static pivoting methods such as using `PIVOT` Clause, and `Conditional Aggregation`, *in which all the resulting pivoted columns should be specified explicitly*, while there's **no** direct dynamic method through using **SQL only**.

I think using `SYS_REFCURSOR` within a stored function would suit well for your case :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
   Get_Table1_RS(
                  i_number        table1."number"%TYPE
                 ) RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
  v_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_sql       VARCHAR2(32767);
  v_str       VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  SELECT LISTAGG( ''''||time||''' AS "'||LOWER(c.column_name)||t.rn||'"' , ',' ) 
                 WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY time )
    INTO v_str
    FROM ( SELECT t1.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY time) AS rn 
             FROM table1 t1
            WHERE "number" = '001' ) t 
    LEFT JOIN user_tab_cols c
      ON c.table_name = 'TABLE1' 
     AND c.column_name like 'TIME%';  

  v_sql :=
  'SELECT *
     FROM table1
    PIVOT
    (
     MAX(time) FOR time IN ( '|| v_str ||' )
    )
    WHERE "number" = :nr';

  OPEN v_recordset FOR v_sql USING i_number;
  RETURN v_recordset;
END;
/
```

in order to get dynamically generated result set(eg. **Dynamic Pivot**).

Then run the below code :

```
VAR rc REFCURSOR
EXEC :rc := Get_Table1_RS('001');
PRINT rc
```

from SQL Developer's Command Line in order to see the result set.

If you still want to use SQL Query only, then prefer using :

The case with **pivot** clause :

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1
 PIVOT 
   (
    MAX(time) FOR time IN ( '12:30' AS "time1",'14:31' AS "time2",
                            '17:20' AS "time3",'19:01' AS "time4" )
   )
 WHERE "number" = '001';


   
  number date         time1 time2 time3 time4
  ------ -----------  ----- ----- ----- -----
  001    19.09.2020   12:30 14:31 17:20 19:01
```

The case with **conditional aggregation** :

```
SELECT "number", "date", 
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN time END) AS "time1",
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN time END) AS "time2",
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN time END) AS "time3",
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN time END) AS "time4"  
  FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY time) AS rn,
                t1.*
           FROM table1 t1
          WHERE "number" = '001' ) t  
 GROUP BY "number", "date"    

  number date         time1 time2 time3 time4
  ------ -----------  ----- ----- ----- -----
  001    19.09.2020   12:30 14:31 17:20 19:01
```

Comment: would like to mention one point, I think the same row number we can use in the pivoting clause as well instead the time column. ( Could gain some characters against 4000 limit for listagg :) )

Comment: yes it was also possible @Sujitmohanty30 , but asterisk was enough :)